# Graphs without K4 minor have minimum degree at most 2

Tags: graph-theory

This is a proven special case of Hadwiger's conjecture. But all the proofs I have seen so far are quite messy. Does someone know a nice short proof for this?

Comment: Graphs with minimum degree at most 2 are 3-colourable by induction. $K_{3,3}$ has a $K_4$ minor (1st vertex on left, 1st right + 2nd left, 2nd right + 3rd left, 3rd right). My assertion is correct I think.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to show with your $K_n$, sorry, explain it please. $K_n$ for $n\geq 5$ has a $K_4$ minor, so it is not covered by my assertion at all? What is your point?

Comment: Ahh, I get your intention. My statement "minum degree at most 2, then 3-colourable" was not well put, you provided the counterexample. However, if we show that Graphs without $K_4$ minor have minimum degree at most 2, it follows that such graphs are 3-colourable (because after removing a vertex of degree at most 2, the remaining graph still has no $K_4$ minor and thus minimum degree at most 2, so we can apply induction). So the above assertion indeed implies Hadwiger case 4.